# アプリを起動するとアイコンバッジ設定がOFFになる

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, push-notification

Remote NotificationとLocal Notificationを受信した場合にアプリアイコンにバッジを表示しようとしています。

Xcode 6.1.1　/　検証端末はiPhone5S iOS8.2です。

AppDelegate内で以下のようにNotificationTypeを指定しています。

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]    respondsToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotifications)]) {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];

} else {

    UIRemoteNotificationType types =UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert| UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:types];
}
```

Remote NotificationからBadgeを付与すると以下のWarningが出ました。

```
Attempting to badge the application icon but haven't received permission from the   user to badge the application
```

iPhoneの設定の"通知"を確認すると
開発アプリの"Appアイコンバッジ表示"がOFFになっていたのでONに変更し、
再度Remote Notificationを送信しました。
そうすると、Badgeを表示することができました。

しかしその後、Xcodeから再度アプリを起動すると、また同じWarningが出たので、
Settingを確認すると、"Appアイコンバッジ表示"がまたOFFになっていました。

どうやら、アプリを起動するたびにバッジのみ、OFFになってしまうようです。
サウンド、バナーについてはONのままです。

なぜアプリ起動するとバッジの設定がリセットされてしまうのか、
ご存知の方がいましたら教えていただけませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOSアップデートで解決しました。
もしかするとiOSの不具合だったのかもしれません。
(ソースは変えていないので...)